# Pip fails to install library and I don't know why (chatterbot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi, chatterbot

So its what it says in the title, I can't seem to figure out why it happens, and I'm kind of new to python and it seems like a bunch of nonsense for me, I,ve installed a lot of other libraries before and all of them work fine, pip is up to date... Hope someone can help:

```
C:\Users\NOEL\Desktop\Folders\Python\DiscBot>pip install chatterbot
```

```
Collecting chatterbot
  Using cached ChatterBot-1.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting pint>=0.8.1
  Using cached Pint-0.16.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (205 kB)
Collecting sqlalchemy<1.3,>=1.2
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-1.2.19.tar.gz (5.7 MB)
Collecting pymongo<4.0,>=3.3
  Using cached pymongo-3.11.0.tar.gz (771 kB)
Collecting mathparse<0.2,>=0.1
  Using cached mathparse-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (7.2 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\noel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from chatterbot) (2020.4)
Requirement already satisfied: nltk<4.0,>=3.2 in c:\users\noel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from chatterbot) (3.5)
Collecting spacy<2.2,>=2.1
  Using cached spacy-2.1.9.tar.gz (30.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\noel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\noel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\NOEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-gwptr5s2\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (79 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-50.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
  Collecting wheel<0.33.0,>0.32.0
    Using cached wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
  Collecting Cython
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Using cached cymem-2.0.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (36 kB)
  Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
    Using cached preshed-2.0.1.tar.gz (113 kB)
  Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
    Using cached murmurhash-1.0.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (21 kB)
  Collecting thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8
    Using cached thinc-7.0.8.tar.gz (1.9 MB)
  Collecting blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.1
    Using cached blis-0.2.4.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9
    Using cached wasabi-0.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
  Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6
    Using cached srsly-1.0.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (287 kB)
  Collecting numpy>=1.7.0
    Using cached numpy-1.19.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (13.0 MB)
  Collecting plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6
    Using cached plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
  Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0
    Using cached tqdm-4.51.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (70 kB)
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for preshed, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for thinc, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for blis, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython, cymem, preshed, murmurhash, numpy, blis, wasabi, srsly, plac, tqdm, thinc
      Running setup.py install for preshed: started
      Running setup.py install for preshed: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\noel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\NOEL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q7fs79vj\\preshed\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\NOEL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q7fs79vj\\preshed\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\NOEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-r7wwov9n\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\NOEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-gwptr5s2\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\NOEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-gwptr5s2\overlay\Include\preshed'
           cwd: C:\Users\NOEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q7fs79vj\preshed\
      Complete output (41 lines):
      WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
      copying preshed\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
      copying preshed\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
      copying preshed\tests\test_counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
      copying preshed\tests\test_hashing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
      copying preshed\tests\test_pop.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
      copying preshed\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
      copying preshed\counter.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
      copying preshed\maps.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
      copying preshed\counter.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
      copying preshed\maps.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
      copying preshed\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
      running build_ext
      building 'preshed.maps' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\preshed
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\noel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\noel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\noel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /EHsc /Tppreshed/maps.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\preshed/maps.obj /Ox /EHsc
      maps.cpp
      preshed/maps.cpp(5728): error C2039: "tp_print": no es un miembro de "_typeobject"
      c:\users\noel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: vea la declaraci¢n de '_typeobject'
      preshed/maps.cpp(5740): error C2039: "tp_print": no es un miembro de "_typeobject"
      c:\users\noel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: vea la declaraci¢n de '_typeobject'
      preshed/maps.cpp(5749): error C2039: "tp_print": no es un miembro de "_typeobject"
      c:\users\noel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: vea la declaraci¢n de '_typeobject'
      preshed/maps.cpp(5755): error C2039: "tp_print": no es un miembro de "_typeobject"
      c:\users\noel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: vea la declaraci¢n de '_typeobject'
      preshed/maps.cpp(5761): error C2039: "tp_print": no es un miembro de "_typeobject"
      c:\users\noel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: vea la declaraci¢n de '_typeobject'
      preshed/maps.cpp(5767): error C2039: "tp_print": no es un miembro de "_typeobject"
      c:\users\noel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: vea la declaraci¢n de '_typeobject'
      preshed/maps.cpp(6129): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
      preshed/maps.cpp(6145): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\noel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\NOEL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q7fs79vj\\preshed\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\NOEL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q7fs79vj\\preshed\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\NOEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-r7wwov9n\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\NOEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-gwptr5s2\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\NOEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-gwptr5s2\overlay\Include\preshed' Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\noel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\noel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\NOEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-gwptr5s2\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0' Check the logs for full command output.
```

> *Note: I alredy tried installing vs build tools 2019

Comment: Error `'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'` means that the code is intended for a different version of Python. The `tp_print` method was removed from the API in Python 3.8.

Comment: So that means the library is only for python 2?

Comment: It's for Python <= 3.7.

Comment: do you know if its possible to have two python versions installed?

Comment: It's possible to have a dozen. I use all Pythons: 2.7 and 3.4+ (and on w32 every Python is doubled for 32- and 64-bit) to test my libraries. But you have to understand that every Python has its set of installed packages; I need to install a long list of dependencies for every version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was only able to install it using, i found in another forum:

```
pip install chatterbot==1.0.2
```

Or installing another python version